# Does there exist a word with H sounds like [eɪtʃ]?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

I'm not a native English speaker, but the question is interesting.  I've never met such a word.  I mean the word is not an initialism (like PhD) or acronym.

Comment: No, h tends to be silent unless it stands alone. https://pronunciationstudio.com/h/

Comment: If you've never met such a word, what makes you think one might exist?

Comment: There are so many interesting things that we don't know.  Even if I have never met it, why can't it exist?

Comment: The sets {words} and {acronyms} are usually not considered disjoint (though I don't wish to open a debate on where the line is supposed to be). The words 'radar' and 'scuba', for instance,  are certainly in the lexicon. But some might consider them to have stopped being acronyms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd go so far as to say that many people don't even know that they are acronyms until people point it out. So, that's probably a reasonable way of deciding when they became words themselves.

Comment: Are there any other consonants who are ever pronounced as their standalone alphabet names when they form part of a word? Is the letter z ever pronounced /zed/? Is a b ever pronounced /biː/? I can think of no such examples (unless you count things like _B movie_, which I don’t – that’s the letter as a letter, not as part of a word). Only vowels have pronunciations that correspond to their alphabet names as part of a word (and not even y, which doesn’t).

Comment: @David M The perennial question: _How many people_? There's an ongoing debate on ELU about when 'wordification' occurs. _If one person uses a candidate?_ or  _if one person uses it and thereby conveys a meaning to a second?_ or _If a reasonable (!?!) number of people use and understand the word?_ or _when it appears in Wiktionary?_ or _when it appears in OED?_

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It’s an interesting question for sake of trivia. In AmE, z’s pronunciation can be found in “zebra”, b’s in “beet”. h, judging from the answers so far, really only has its phonetic spelling “aitch”.

Comment: @cole No, in those words, the z and b represent /z/ and /b/, respectively, just like in _buzz_ or _bus_. What represents /ziː/ and /biː/ (the alphabet names) is _ze_ and _bee_, respectively, vowels included.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I realize that those examples didn’t explain what I was going for. I meant the syllables like in _ze_ or _bee_, not the individual phonemes. My interpretation is that the question asks whether there exists a word that has the pronunciation of the letter h in it. E.g. c’s pronunciation can be found in “seed,” but the letter itself is absent.

Comment: @cole Oh, I see what you mean now. I hadn’t considered that at all as a possibility. That would definitely be a more realistic question – in fact I can’t think of any words that contain the sequence /eɪtʃ/ off the top of my head. This also makes more sense of petitrien’s answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer would have to be no in today's English.  However the noun *ache* used to be pronounced /eitʃ/, like the letter *H*, contrary to the verb *to ache* that had a /k/ consonantal sound.  The OED remarks on it:

> Old English *æce* is a primary derivation of the verb *ac-an* to ache /eik/, in which, as in parallel forms, the *c* /k/ was palatalized to *ch* /tʃ/, while in the verb it remained /k/; cf. *make* — *match*; *bake* — *batch*; *wake* — *watch*; *break* — *breach*; *speak* — *speech*; *stick* — *stitch*.
>
> Occasional early instances of *ake* as noun are northern, in which dialect *c* /k/ was not palatalized, cf. *make* = *match*, *steik* = *stitch*, *kirk* = *church*.
>
> In the 17th century the noun was still *atche* /ɑːtʃ, ɛːtʃ/, plural *atch-es* /ɑːtʃɪz, ɛːtʃɪz/, but about 1700 it began to be confused with the verb as /ɛːk/. The spelling of the latter has in turn been changed to *ache*, so that though both verb and noun are now really *ake*, both are in current spelling written *ache*. 
>   The former pronunciation survives in the dialectal *eddage* = *head-ache*.
>
> The ‘O.P.’ rioters, ignorant of the Shaksperian distinction of ache /eik/ (verb) and ache /eitʃ/ (noun), ridiculed the stage pronunciation of the noun by giving it to the verb in ‘John Kemble's head aitches’.

For the O. P. riots, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Price_Riots

Shakespeare plays on the fact that *H* and *ache* were pronounced the same in *Much Ado about Nothing* (Act III, Scene IV):

> Beatrice: 'Tis almost five o'clock, cousin, 'tis time you were ready.  By my troth, I am exceedingly ill, heigh-ho!
>
> Margaret:  For a hawk, a horse, or a husband?
>
> Beatrice: For the letter that begins them all, H.

A further example is taken from John Heywood's *Hundred Epigrammes* (1550), the 59th of which is about the letter *H* and works only if there is an identity of sound with the noun *ache*:

> 'H' is worst among letters in the cross row,
>
> For if thou find him other in thine elbow,
>
> In thine arme, or leg — in any degree —
>
> In thy head, or teeth, in thy toe or knee,
>
> Into what place soever 'H' may pike him,
>
> Wherever thou find ache, thou shalt not like him.

Mention should also be made of the *aitch-bone* /ˈeɪtʃˌbəʊn/, defined in the OED as follows:

> The bone of the buttock or rump; the cut of beef lying over this bone.